# How to make a bot join voice channels discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm using discord.py to create a music bot, but I'm having trouble connecting the bot to a voice channel. Im using a Cog to seperate the music features from the rest.

```
@commands.command()
async def join_voice(self, ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    print(channel.id)
    await self.client.VoiceChannel.connect()
```

But I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'`

I've looked all through the docs and all the similar questions on here and still no solutions!

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're really close! The only thing you've got to change is:

```py
@commands.command()
async def join_voice(self, ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice
    if connected:
        await connected.channel.connect() #  Use the channel instance you put into a variable
```

What you were doing was grabbing the VoiceChannel class object, and not the actual VoiceChannel instance that the user was connected to. That's where your error came in, as it was trying to find a voice channel which didn't exist.

Glad to see the progress, keep it up!

Comment: I cant believe it its you again! You are literally the best person in the coding universe rn for me! Thanks so much!

Comment: Haha, small world we live in :) No worries!

Comment: one last thing! it now says i need the PyNaCl library so i used ```pip install PyNaCl``` but it wont import to the project

Comment: Are you getting an ImportError?

Comment: the error says ```discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtentionFailed: Extension 'cogs.Music' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyNaCl'```

Comment: Do you have clashing python versions perhaps?

Comment: Nope i only have v3.7

Comment: @LegacyCoding Try `import nacl` instead of `import PyNaCl`

Comment: Brilliant! Happy coding!