# discord.py how do I make my bot join a specific voice channel?

Tags: discord.py

as the title suggests, I am trying to make my bot join a specific voice channel. I found other questions relating to how to make the bot join the authors voice channel. What I am trying to make is, join "x" voice channel. How come I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a bot join voice channels discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61784807/how-to-make-a-bot-join-voice-channels-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

Get the `discord.Channel` instance of the channel, and call it's [`connect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.VoiceChannel.connect) function.

```
channel_id = the_id_of_the_channel_you_want_to_join
voice_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
await voice_channel.connect()
```

Comment: yes, I know that but what I don't understand is that how do you insert that channel id to your bot to join.

Comment: In case you want the bot to always join the same channel, you can right click on a channel to copy it's id. If you don't have a `copy id` button, go to settings and turn on `developer mode`. If you want the bot to join the same channel that the author of the command  is in, you can get their `VoiceState` & get the channel out of that. More info on that in the API docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voicestate#discord.VoiceState